# Removing comma from values in column (csv file) using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to remove commas from a column named size.
CSV looks like below:

```
number   name    size
   1      Car     9,32,123
   2      Bike    1,00,000
   3      Truck   10,32,111
```

I want the output as below:

```
number   name    size
   1      Car     932123
   2      Bike    100000
   3      Truck   1032111
```

I am using `python3` and `Pandas` module for handling this csv.
I am trying `replace` method but I don't get the desired output.

Snapshot from my code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

// df.replace(",","")
// df['size'] = df['size'].replace(to_replace = "," , value = "")
// df['size'] = df['size'].replace(",", "")

df['size'] = df['size'].replace({",", ""})
print(df['size'])  // expecting to see 'size' column without comma
```

I don't see any error/exception. The last line `print(df['size'])` simply displays values as it is, ie, with commas.

Comment: Are you sure that sample you showed represents actual file content?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it is just a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) instead:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Optional convert to `int` with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype):

```
df['size'] = df['size'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

```
   number   name     size
0       1    Car   932123
1       2   Bike   100000
2       3  Truck  1032111
```

---

Sample Frame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['Car', 'Bike', 'Truck'],
                   'size': ['9,32,123', '1,00,000', '10,32,111']})
```

```
   number   name       size
0       1    Car   9,32,123
1       2   Bike   1,00,000
2       3  Truck  10,32,111
```

Answer (score 4):

With `replace`, we need `regex=True` because otherwise it looks for exact match in a cell, i.e., cells with `,` in them only:

```
>>> df["size"] = df["size"].replace(",", "", regex=True)
>>> df

   number   name     size
0       1    Car   932123
1       2   Bike   100000
2       3  Truck  1032111
```

Answer (score 4):

*I am using `python3` and `Pandas` module for handling this csv*

Note that [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function has optional argument `thousands`, if `,` are used for denoting thousands you might set `thousands=","` consider following example

```
import io
import pandas as pd
some_csv = io.StringIO('value\n"1"\n"1,000"\n"1,000,000"\n')
df = pd.read_csv(some_csv, thousands=",")
print(df)
```

output

```
     value
0        1
1     1000
2  1000000
```

For brevity I used `io.StringIO`, same effect might be achieved providing name of file with same content as first argument in `io.StringIO`.

Comment: by far the easiest solution!